# Issue with log4J (1.2.17 version) while renaming Kafka log files on Windows

Tags: windows, logging, apache-kafka, log4j

I am running Kafka version 2.8.0 on Windows platform, which in-turn uses log4J version 1.2.17. I am facing below **log4j:ERROR Failed to rename** issue caused by Log4j on both Zookeeper and Kafka server. Please let me know how to fix this issue ?

**Zookeeper logs:**

```
[ERR] [ZooKeeper] log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [C:\kafka-2.8.0/logs/controller.log] to [C:\kafka-2.8.0/logs/controller.log.2021-07-21-00].
```

**Kafka Server logs:**

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [C:\kafka-2.8.0/logs/controller.log] to [C:\kafka-2.8.0/logs/controller.log.2021-07-21-00].
```

**Note:** This issue is happening frequently for both controller.log and server.log files

Below is the log4J properties file which I am currently using,

**log4j.properties file:**

```
# Unspecified loggers and loggers with additivity=true output to server.log and stdout
# Note that INFO only applies to unspecified loggers, the log level of the child logger is used otherwise
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, kafkaAppender

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Change the line below to adjust ZK client logging
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Change the two lines below to adjust the general broker logging level (output to server.log and stdout)
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

# Uncomment the lines below and change log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$ to TRACE for additional output
# related to the handling of requests
#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false

log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=INFO, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false

# Access denials are logged at INFO level, change to DEBUG to also log allowed accesses
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=INFO, authorizerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=false
```

Comment: 1) Try using backslash for file paths 2) [Don't run Kafka directly on Windows](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/) since it isnt well-tested there and you'll run into other issues with topic data

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried using backslash but it does not fix this issue.

Comment: And what if you use WSL2?

Comment: @VinayGangaraj this issue happens constantly for me too. And I am using Windows. May I ask if you are starting Zookeeper and kafka in CMD or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

As @OneCricketeer advised you should change paths from `/` to `\\`

use 2 backslash in configuration files:

In **C:\kafka\config\zookeeper.properties**:

```
dataDir=c:\\kafka\\zookeeper
```

and in **C:\kafka\config\server.properties**:

```
log.dirs=c:\\kafka\\kafka-logs
```

Also go to **C:\kafka\config\log4j.properties**

Wherever you see something like this:

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
```

Change it to this:

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}\\server.log
```

These are all places where you should change it:

```
Line 26: log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}\\server.log
Line 32: log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}\\state-change.log
Line 38: log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}\\kafka-request.log
Line 44: log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}\\log-cleaner.log
Line 50: log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}\\controller.log
Line 56: log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}\\kafka-authorizer.log
```

Comment: Do you know where ${kafka.logs.dir} is defined in Apache Kafka v3.6.0?

Answer (score 0):

Actually forward vs back slashes won't fix the bug:
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_41600330/article/details/123525153?ydreferer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8%3D

And Kafka is not prioritizing the issue: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/6329

From this Chinese blogger, you need fix DailyRollingFileAppender.java (under log4j, not Kafka). That's a lot of work though.

Easiest remove all file appenders from C:\kafka\kafka_2.12-3.5.0\config\log4j.properties

If you really want to go down rabbit hole, and fix log4j:

1. Install Java, download Kafka source and Gradle (Build Tool):

   https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

   gradle https://gradle.org/install/

   (Create C:\gradle, put it under there. Update system environment variables PATH)
2. Download log4j "apache-log4j-2.20.0-src.tar.gz"
   https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

   Fix DailyRollingFileAppender (Logic moved from **DailyRollingFileAppender**.java to **RollingFileAppender**.java)

   Compile log4j. Replace log4j's jar in Kafka with this version under C:\kafka\kafka_2.13-2.7.0\libs
3. To compile Kafka on MAC:

   gradlew jar

On Windows however,

```
C:\kafka\src\kafka-3.5.1-src
gradle wrapper jar
```

4. To verify build:
   cd C:\kafka\src\kafka-3.5.1-src
   bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties